# Prevent properties dialog from closing during file/path selection

Tags: properties, operator

Given the following code, I have ha dialog box with three with two `StringProperty` properties with `FILE_PATH` AND `DIR_PATH` subtypes.  This allows me to browse to a file and directory respecitvely, however; when the file selection box opens, the dialog cancels out.

How do I get the dialog to stay open until the `OK` button is pressed?

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My Operator"""
    bl_label = "My very own operator"
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"

    text: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Text:", default="")
    update_mesh: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Update mesh(es)?", default=True)
    library_file: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = 'Library File:',
        description = 'Library File Path',
        default = '',
        maxlen = 1024,
        subtype = 'FILE_PATH'
    )
    working_dir: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = 'Working Directory:',
        description = 'Main project directory',
        default = '',
        maxlen = 1024,
        subtype = 'DIR_PATH'
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        #do some stuff
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myOp)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myOp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: I think opening the fileselect box is also an instance of `window_manager.invoke_props_dialog`  internally so it overrides the underlying dialogue. I don't think these props are meant to be used in this way although it is possible. Maybe there is a way to have two distinct window manager popup dialogs but I don't know how personaly.

Comment: Have you tried swapping out `invoke_props_dialog()` for any of these other [options](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog)? There are about 10 of em.

Comment: @Jakemoyo I have also tried `invoke_props_popup` and `invoke_popup`.  Since these go away when the cursor leaves the boundary, they also disappear when either the `DIR_PATH` or `FILE_PATH` selectors are clicked.  At this point, I'm thinking it might be more prudent to go with a panel, rather than a dialog for selecting the options.